# Finding z-index value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to find a z-index value of a element by jQuery?

i.e.:
I have 2 divs, both are positioned absolute and z-index 10, 1000 respectively.

But unfortunately IE6 displaying second div which has z-index 1000 below the first one.

So I want to check what the z-index value of second one and first one at run time in IE6.

Please help.

Answer (score 27):

You can get it using `css`.

```
$("#your-div").css("z-index");
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: that will only show the z-index that is set in css. It may just say 'auto' or similar. YOu want to use $().zIndex() instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$('selector').zIndex()`.

DO NOT USE `$('selector').css('z-index')`. It will only tell you what (if anything) was set in the style sheet. It may just say "auto".

Comment: It's __zIndex()__. Camel case.

Comment: The `zIndex` function as been removed in the latest version of jQuery-ui.

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#removed-zindex

Answer (score 5):

If they have IDs for example (or any selector you can find them by) use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), like this:

```
var zIndex = $("#div1").css('z-index');
```

Or the more complete:

```
alert("Div 1 zIndex: " + $("#div1").css('z-index'));
alert("Div 2 zIndex: " + $("#div2").css('z-index'));
```

Comment: Thanks dear,
But IE display it "undefined"

Comment: @Baljit - If IE is displaying undefined...then they're getting no `z-index`, which would be the problem :) What selector are you using to set the `z-index`? is it a CSS selector that IE doesn't understand/handle?

Comment: I am using z-index which was wrong, it is zIndex actually. Now it is ok. 
Thanks for helping
baljit

Answer (score 4):

Like the [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function ?

```
alert($('#my_object_id').css('zIndex'));
```

Comment: Thanks dear,
But IE display it "undefined"

Comment: My bad, `zIndex` for `css()`, not `z-index`.

Comment: just for anyone's interest, either works (at least now):  
  
code:  
    var z0 = _element.css('zIndex'),  
    z1 = _element.css('z-index'),  
    z2 = _element.css('z_index');  
  
chrome locals:  
    z0: "auto"  
    z1: "auto"  
    z2: undefined

Answer (score 2):

Besides using

```
$('selector').css('z-index')
```

you have to add `postion:absolute` or `position:relative` in your styles to element with z-index you want to get.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery provides methods to directly set and get [z-index](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/zIndex/#zIndex-zIndex) of any element

Syntax:

```
var index = $("#div1").zIndex()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(elem).css('z-index');
```

Also, where are you setting the z-indexes. If it's in an inline style vs a style block, then you may see different results. So:

```
<div style="z-index: 1000">..</div>
```

vs

```
<style>
div {
    z-index: 1000;
}
</style>
```

may give different results. Also, remember that going by your logic is an exercise in vain with IE.

Comment: Thanks dear,
But IE display it "undefined"

Comment: @Baljit - So now the next most important question is where and how are you setting the z-index?

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be broken. Check this, **[it works](http://jsbin.com/anuza/2/)**.

If you don't set a `z-index` value *FF* and *Chrome* will display `auto`, and *IE* `0`.

`Undefined` means there is some **error in your code**.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like

```
var zindex = $("#id").css("z-index");
```

Answer (score 0):

use zIndex instead of z-index.

$('selector').css('zIndex');

Comment: This is the same thing, jQuery normalizes CSS names internally, turning any caps to `-lower`, so [`zIndex` gets transformed to `z-index`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L129) by doing this: `.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1" ).toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple recursive function to get the exact zIndex value in number

```
function getRecursiveParentZIndex(jqThis) {
  try {
    let thisTagName = jqThis.prop('tagName');

    let thisZIndex = jqThis.css('z-index');
    if (thisZIndex == '' || thisZIndex == 'auto') {
      thisZIndex = 0;
      if (thisTagName != 'HTML') {
        let newZIndex = getRecursiveParentZIndex(jqThis.parent());
        thisZIndex = newZIndex;
      }
    }

    return +thisZIndex;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('parent Z Index error', error);

    return 0;
  }
}

let correctZindex = getRecursiveParentZIndex(jQuery('.your-selector'));
```

This will return the correct z-index value in number.
(Note that i used ES6 syntax)